# Flask-Migrate Access denied for user 'root'@'10.x.x.x' (using password: YES)

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-migrate

I'm working on Flask-Migrate with mysql.

And I received error message like this:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'10.x.x.x' (using password: YES)")

mysql is live with docker, I try to connect with following commands and it works fine:

```
mysql -u root -h {mysql_host} -P {mysql_port} -p
```

Plus it works very fine with sqlalchemy like this:

```
class DatabaseClient():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__settings__ = settings
    

        alchemy_string = 'mysql+mysqldb://root:{password}@{mysql_host}:{mysql_port}/main?charset=utf8mb4'
        self.__engine__ = sqlalchemy.create_engine(alchemy_string, echo=False)
        self.__conn__ = self.__engine__.connect()

        self.session = self.__conn__
    
    def get(self, query: str) -> pandas.DataFrame:
        result = self.__conn__.execute(sqlalchemy.text(query))
        
        return pandas.DataFrame(result.fetchall())


    def execute(self, query: str):
        return self.__conn__.execute(sqlalchemy.text(query))

    def commit(self):
        self.__conn__.commit()


client = DatabaseClient()
query_str = f'''
    select * from contents
'''
df_result = client.get(query_str)
print(df_result)

del client
```

But, when I tried to use Flask-Migrate for ORM features, it respond with the error message.
Here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

import sys
sys.path.append('../../')

from apps._common.database_client import DatabaseSettings, DatabaseType
from database.pio_d1.model import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqldb://root:{password}@{mysql_host):{mysql_port}/main?charset=utf8mb4'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

print(app.config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```

```
flask db init
flask db migrate
```

and here's error codes:

```
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3293, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1268, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 283, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'10.x.x.x' (using password: YES)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 1063, in main
    cli.main()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 357, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_migrate/cli.py", line 91, in migrate
    _migrate(directory, message, sql, head, splice, branch_label, version_path,
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 96, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 210, in migrate
    command.revision(config, message, autogenerate=True, sql=sql,
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 236, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 582, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 94, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 110, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/dev/database/database/pio_d1/migrations/env.py", line 96, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/home/dev/database/database/pio_d1/migrations/env.py", line 81, in run_migrations_online
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3269, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 147, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2431, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3293, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1268, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 283, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/database/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'10.x.x.x' (using password: YES)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Any insights or suggestions are very welcomed!

Many thanks

JK

Comment: Not really sure what you expect from us here as the error message in this particular case is clear: either your mysql user name or the password is incorrect. Please be aware that the IP address or the host name of the computer you connect **from** is also part of the user name.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `10.x.x.x` address that the error complains about. Then make sure the `root` user is configured in your MySQL server with access from that URL. Chances are you only have the user set up to access from localhost.